# REGEX: "Invalid pattern in look-behind" assertion

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds

I’m trying to write a regex substitution for markup-ish text. I try to catch every line that is not empty and does not start with any number of hashtags.

I tried to catch just the content using the negative lookbehind assertion so find lines that start with any number of hashtags followed by a space.

Here is what I tried with a negative lookbehind:

`/^(?<!#+ )(.*?)$/i`

My searched text looks similar like this:

```
# heading

## part
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

## part
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I get the error `invalid pattern in look-behind`, and I don’t understand it. Could you help me?

Comment: You need a **lookahead**. `/^(?!#+ ).*$/`.

Comment: The pattern is invalid because you have a variable length in the assertion. Basically a quantifier after the pound sign. Aside from that,  if variable length were allowed in Ruby look behind assertions, this type of beginning `^(?<!#)` will always be true because there can be _nothing_ before the beginning of string _and_ there is only a line-break before the beginning of line if in line mode `(?m)`.

Comment: just as @WiktorStribiżew said. Or you can move one character and do a look behind for `#` like  /^.(?<!#)/

Comment: Basically the regex you're looking for is this `(?m)^(?!#).*\S.*` which will match any line that does not start with a hash tag and the line must contain at least one non-whitespace character.

Comment: Ah, I see. It’s still a lookahead because it is AFTER the start of a line. That was the bug in my mind. Thank you all for your answers, also the other ones. I think I now understand the concept better. You’re great!

Comment: does /^[^#]+/gmi make sense?